# Como detectar startNestedScroll(int) em WebView personalizado?

Tags: android, webview

Eu tenho um WebView customizada dentro de uma ViewPager customizado o qual tem um scroll na Vertical. Eu preciso fazer um scroll no viewPager quando o scroll da webview chegar ao final.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você precisa detectar que houve um "overscroll" (cima ou baixo) e mudar de página no ViewPager (anterior ou próxima) ou fazer o scroll simultâneo? Ou nada disso?

Comment: Utilizo um Transformer no meu ViewPager e ele faz scroll na vertical e nao na horizontal, e dentro de cada pagina do ViewPager tem um WebView que por padrao tambem faz scroll na vertical, eu gostaria de que quando o scroll na vertical do WebView chegasse ao fim ele "passasse" o poder de scroll para o ViewPager trocar de pagina.